# Erro ao usar else: "'else' without a previous 'if'"

Tags: c, if

Estou tentando fazer um programa básico, mas parei na metade porque deu o erro:

> error:'else' without a previous 'if'

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int med1, med2, med3;
    printf("\nDigite a medida 1 : ");
    scanf("%f", &med1);
    printf("\nDigite a medida 2 : ");
    scanf("%f", &med2);
    printf("\nDigite a medida 3 : ");
    scanf("%f", &med3);
    if((med1+med2>med3) && (med2+med3>med1) && (med1+med3>med2));
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
    else;
    {
        printf("Medidas não formam um triangulo");
        return (0);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Você colocou um ; ao final do if o que encerrou o comando. Troque 
if((med1+med2>med3) && (med2+med3>med1) && (med1+med3>med2)); por 
if((med1+med2>med3) && (med2+med3>med1) && (med1+med3>med2)) Idem após o else.

Comment: E tem outro `;` logo depois do `else`, retire-o também

Answer (score 2):

Você tem diversos problemas em seu algoritmo, irei apontar somente os problemas de sintaxes o qual se refere a sua pergunta:

**Linha 16**

```
error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
```

**Qual o problema que está acusando?**

> O `else` não possui um `if`.. Isto porque você está utilizando o carácter `;` na palavra reservada `if` e `else`, o qual está causando problema com a sintaxe na hora da compilação do algoritmo.

Vamos analisar o seu algoritmo direto ao erro:

```
if((med1+med2>med3) && (med2+med3>med1) && (med1+med3>med2)); << REMOVA O (;)
{ 
    //código
} else; // << REMOVA O (;)
{ 
    //código
}
```

Para que o compilador entenda a sintaxe do seu algoritmo, você poderá fazer de duas maneiras este trecho do código, as quais são as seguintes:

**I) REMOVER O CARÁCTER** `;` **E O RETURN DENTRO DO** `ELSE`**, E ALINHA CORRETAMENTE POR BOAS PRÁTICAS AS CHAVES** `{}`

```
if((med1+med2>med3) && (med2+med3>med1) && (med1+med3>med2)) { 
   //código
} else {
   //código
}
```

**II) REMOVER O CARÁCTER** `;`**, E CRIE UM OPERADOR TERNÁRIO COM A ESTRUTURA DE CONDIÇÕES**

```
(med1+med2>med3) && (med2+med3>med1) && (med1+med3>med2) ? printf("\n") : printf("Medidas não formam um triangulo");
```

**NOTA:**

> PARA ENTENDER MELHOR COMO FUNCIONA O COMPILADOR DE UMA LINGUAGEM DE PROGRAMAÇÃO, VOCÊ DEVE ESTUDAR OS SEGUINTES CONTEÚDOS:
>
> - Autômatos Ling. Formais e Computabilidade
> - Compiladores

Answer (score 0):

Você colocou erroneamente um ; logo após a condição do if e também logo após o else.
Declarou suas variáveis como int mas utiliza a flag %f na leitura, que se destina a float.
Tem um return (0); desnecessário dentro do bloco else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    float med1, med2, med3; 
    printf("\nDigite a medida 1 : "); 
    scanf("%f", &med1); 
    printf("\nDigite a medida 2 : "); 
    scanf("%f", &med2); 
    printf("\nDigite a medida 3 : "); 
    scanf("%f", &med3); 
    if((med1+med2>med3) && (med2+med3>med1) && (med1+med3>med2)) { 
        printf("\n"); /* Será que não deveria ter mais coisas aqui? */
    } else { 
        printf("Medidas não formam um triangulo"); 
    } 
    return(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem um erro no `if` e no `else`, estes comandos em bloco (if-else, for, while, do-while, switch-case..) não levam o `;`.

Veja teu `if` e `else`:

```
if((med1+med2>med3) && (med2+med3>med1) && (med1+med3>med2));
{
    // código
}
else;
{
    // código
}
```

Ele deveria estar assim:

```
if((med1+med2>med3) && (med2+med3>med1) && (med1+med3>med2))
{
    // código
}
else
{
    // código
}
```

Basta remover aqueles `;`.

Edit.: Outro ponto importante, todo código fora do bloco será executado por padrão, no caso do teu `else` não há necessidade de colocar `return 0;` dentro dele, pois o mesmo será executado depois. Imagine que exista mais código após esta condicional, ele simplesmente não seria executado, pois com o `return 0;` tu finalizou a execução do programa.

**O que é `return 0;`?**
Ele é um indicador para o computador de que o teu programa foi executado com sucesso, ou seja, sem erros, o `zero` é um valor padrão.